# iOS - Getting the application AppStore's stats with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ios, drupal, app-store

Is there any way to retrieve information on how many people have downloaded my app on the AppStore.

I would like to retrieve the information and display in a dashboard I develop in Drupal, Google analythics has an API that you can get the statistics and I was thinking about there is something similar to appstore?

Comment: You can see the stats for yourself in iTunesConnect. Unfortunately there's no publicly documented API for this information, although Felix Krause has recently thrown together some documentation at https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs. There are some Mac apps gathering sales information as well, maybe they have more info. DailySales is one of them for example. See http://dailysalesapp.com.

Comment: I will be looking in to that, thank you Kilian